Almost useless list of filtered options in review queue on mobile
A review queue can be filtered by tags and other options (e.g., close reasons).  I believe that it looks fine on a desktop, but it's not OK on mobile. For instance, on enSO not all conditions are visible:



It's even weirder on non-English sites, like ruSO, due to different sizes of words:



On the latter case it's completely unusable.
